# Which ML algorithm should I use for this task?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, data-science

I've a dataset with symptoms and diseases. Each disease contains symptoms with weights (according to the importance). The problem is that supervised approaches not possible to use in this case, since I don't have a test set (I've just table with connections between symps and diseases). I used already an approach with calculating matched symptoms by importance, but it fails if symptom is not the same as in the dataset.

I wonder is there any possible to train a model which will be able to understand hidden connections between different symptoms and give at least approximate result if we chose not the same but very similar symptom. Example: Flu has a cough, but person chose dry cough. The model should consider similarity between two symptoms based on different diseases.

If you have any advice in terms of literature or name of algorithms I would be very grateful.

UPD 1: Example:

[image: Example of data for Bronchitis]

Example of the data for Bronchitis

The main idea is to get a probable disease based on defined symptoms. For now, I'm matching symptoms and sum the matched weights i.e. if we chose Cough + Respiratory Sound it will be 0.441887+0.144301. However, this approach is not flexible and very strict. The aim is to train a model which will be able to cope with similar symptoms. If we choose 'Dry Cough' it shouldn't give 0.44 but also not 0.0

I have a dataset with 1949 unique diseases and 151 symptoms. Each disease contains at least 4 symptoms.

Comment: This type of questions better fits https://datascience.stackexchange.com/, so I'd suggest opening this question there since it is not a programming question, but rather a theoretical one.

Comment: can you give more details like giving a sample of the data you have and describing how many rows of data you have in total, also give a more precise problem definition, like what are you input variables and what are you trying to predict?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I would suggest you keep using the sum for the symptoms that match what you have in your dataset but to use a simple trick for the symptoms that you don't have.
You should use a similarity ration (in case of strings you should start by using **Levenshtein**), that would give how similar new symptoms to all the symptoms you have in the dataset, then find the most similar, usually the one with the highest similarity ratio, and since this ration is between O and 1, you can just use the formula:

*new_weight = similarity_ratio * old_weight*

to get new_weight which is the weight you would use for the new symptom (it would definitely be smaller than the old weight but it would be smaller the more dissimilar the names of the symptoms are)

**example:**

Dry Cough + Respiratory Sound + Fever:

(Dry Cough is most similar to Cough -in the data you've given- and assuming the similarity between Dry Cough and Cough is: .6)

your weight for Bronchitis becomes:

(.6*0.441887) + 0.144301 + 0.013444

*This is just a starting point, rely on it to develop a more powerful approach*

Comment: do you think that Levenshtein Distance would be a good idea for a similarity calculation? I was thinking is there any way to give similarity by co-occurence in difference diseases. For example, headache and vomiting should be nearly close

Comment: you can either use Levenshtein or some more powerful approach like word embedding which will be able to uncover semantic similarity between words (since Levenshtein can't if the words don't have similar characters)  but you should maybe find a word embedding that is specialized to medicine or build your own, as I said I think this is a good starting point but there is all sort of things you can change.